# Ignore case when data binding to SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a DropDownList which binds its SelectedValue to a field from an SqlDataSource. However, I need it to ignore the case when data binding, as if it's not in the correct case I recieve a lot of errors. Is this easily achievable?

Comment: SelectedValue should not be user-entered and therefore case-sensitive should not matter.

Comment: I know, the best approach would be using a PK to bind, but sadly I'm unable to change the structure of the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by simply converting everything to lower in the SQL. Not ideal but it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to SQL or don't want to change your query then do this from code behind.

```
.............
dropDown.DataBind();

foreach (ListItem t in dropDown.Items)
    t.Text = t.Text.ToUpper();// or t.Text.ToLower()
```

If you want to capitalize first letter see this : [Output database values to dropdown in uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410661/output-database-values-to-dropdown-in-uppercase/37411249)