# Output database values to dropdown in uppercase

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a very simple form (in asp.net), some of the fields being populated from db tables. One of them is a dropdownlist with country names. These names are in lowercase in the table, but I would like to do the following:

- display them with the first letter in uppercase
- keep their value in lowercase, so that when the form is submitted, the country names are stored the same way as they were retrieved.

ex. in html we may have an option like this:

```
<option value="montenegro">Montenegro</option>
```

The user sees "Montenegro", yet submits "montenegro".

I know this could be implemented in other ways (like converting the case with the queries, but I was curious whether this method is possible or not).
Also, maybe answers to this question do exist, but I was not able to find one that I thought fit the question and was clear enough.

Comment: You can simply Convert first letter to Capital and rest of value in lower and value of dropdown in lower case by using `ToLower()` method.

Comment: @Mairajahmad yes, that would be it, obviously. However, I have 0 experience with asp.net and would not know where to get each value and convert it.

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
protected string UppercaseFirst(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return string.Empty;

    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

After dropdown databind call the foreach :

```
    dropDown.DataTextField = "ColumnName";
    dropDown.DataValueField = "ColumnName";
    dropDown.DataBind();

 foreach (ListItem t in dropDown.Items)
        t.Text = UppercaseFirst(t.Text);
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the clear, simple, efficient answer that takes care of the specific case and yet can be used in many other cases. I actually learned something today

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string name = "mairaj";
name = name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1, name.Length - 1).ToLower();
```

Above code will make **"mairaj"** To **"Mairaj"**

To convert a `string` into `LowerCase` completely use `ToLower()` function like

```
string country = "PAKIstan";
country = country.ToLower(); //This will make "PAKIstan" to "pakistan"
```